# Which is the correct way to check if a session is still running? Which are some ways?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

So I have already had my first experience with Web Design, but there were some things I did in a certain way that I didn't like, mainly because of time. So anyway, I don't know which is the correct way to handle sessions. What I did in my previous project was to embed PHP into HTML and based on whatever was in $_SESSION, usually an id and a user type number, then I'd open or close parts of the website to the user, through embedded PHP.

However, this is not how I wanted to do this initially, at first what I wanted to do was to make a JavaScript code to send a request through AJAX to the server, and check if the session was still active, and based on that open/close parts of the website, but then I'd have to make a request on every page and every so often to make sure the user is logged in. Should I handle something like this client-side?

What are some other ways to check the session but without embedding PHP and using JavaScript instead to modify the HTML document.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Sessions will expire after X seconds of non-activity (depending on your PHP config) so you might get away with just a JavaScript timer. Of course your user may logout using another window/tab, and an AJAX op would fix this - but repeatedly checking on a timer is rather wasteful of bandwidth (especially on mobile devices, where data can be expensive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, all you need is an ajax request on loop and a php file to check the session.

The Javascript

```
function checkLogin(un) { //put this function in a loop of some sort depending on how you want to use it
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      logout(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "checklogin.php?un=" + un, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function logout(resp) {
  if (resp == "false") { //comparing actual text, not boolean
    window.location.href = 'logout.php'; //destroy the session or something
  }
}
```

The PHP file checklogin.php (very simple)

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION[$_GET['un']] != true) {
  echo 'false';
}
?>
```

The php will depend on how you store your sessions, but in this case it is just using one session titled by their username that stores `true` if signed in. I would recommend making this more complex if you decide to actually use it.

Comment: I see, this might seem like a good solution to be honest. Thank you for the suggestion.